# Un type particulier de répétition dans la phrase

Tags: syntaxe, france, figure-de-style

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> (caractère gras de user LPH)
> Mais, si Landry était trop animé dans son
> amour pour y mettre de la prudence, en revanche,
> **la petite Fadette**, qui avait un esprit porté au
> mystère, et qui, d’ailleurs, ne voulait pas mettre
> Landry trop à l’épreuve des taquineries du
> monde, **la petite Fadette**, qui en fin de compte
> l’aimait trop pour consentir à lui causer des
> peines dans sa famille, exigea de lui un si grand
> secret qu’ils passèrent environ un an avant que la
> chose se découvrît.

La répétition dans la phrase de Sand n'est pas ce qui pourrait sembler être une anomalie à un lecteur peu avancé dans l'étude du français, mais une répétition selon un schéma connu et peut-être toujours d'un usage bien vivant. Je ne peux pas situer une période précise de validité. Néanmoins il me semble qu'il s'agit d'une pratique qui mérite une certaine documentation.

1. Comment définir la fonction de cette répétition ?
2. Est-ce qu'on la classe dans les figures de style ? s'agit-il vraiment de la [symploque](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symploque) ? J'en doute plutôt.
3. Il existe probablement un terme pour y référer ; quel est ce terme ?
4. Dans le français contemporain quelle importance donne-t-on à cette possibilité de répétition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est une anaphore dont la fonction est à mon avis autant de ne pas perdre le lecteur dans une longue chaîne de subordonnées que de donner du rythme et de l'impact a la narration. Enlevez la répétition ou remplacez-la par "elle qui" et la construction devient laborieuse, moins intelligible.

En lecture a voix haute, c'est aussi l'occasion de marquer une légère pause pour reprendre son souffle et repartir avec plus d'intensité en "enfonçant le clou" sur la deuxième occurrence.

Comment: Une réponse très satisfaisante, dont tous les détails mettent en valeur  immédiatement ce que  l'on ressent à la lecture de la phrase de Sand sans pouvoir identifier précisément ces effets.

Comment: Après une vérification sommaire, je suis curieux de savoir si en fait vous ne parleriez pas d'anaphore grammaticale.

Comment: Possible que ça en soit une, mais je faisais référence a la figure de style littéraire/réthorique.